# Sencha app with Cordova on Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I am trying to build a ios package using sencha and phone gap. I followed the steps here http://vimeo.com/56673251. I am able to build and run the package on ios simulator. However, I can only see the index.html page. All the model, view and controller folders with js files created by sencha are not copied there. So, I am not able to run the app which i built using sencha. 
When i click on the app/view/Main.js i get error  The requested URL was not found on this server.
Any help on this would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that they expect you to run only the "production" version of you app inside cordova. When you set production the microloader is not used and everything is compiled into one file instead. That should solve the issue.